# Delay in occurring secured key while typing password in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

In my project I have the password as textfield, I have made the textfield as secured, Still while typing the text, the user can see the text for few second, I have to restrict it, 
I have also tried with `textfield.isSecureTextEntry` its not working
please give some suggestions

Comment: You can also set textfield as secureTextentry in storyboard. Select the textfield in the storyboard, go to Attributes inspector, under Text Input Traits - select the checkbox Secure Text Entry.

Comment: Can you add all the code you have used

Comment: You are describing standard iOS behaviour.  The intention is to allow the user to see that they have typed the correct letter.  You will probably need to make your own onscreen keyboard using `UIButtons` if you don't want the standard `UITextField` behaviour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I might consider setting up a GCD in textFieldDidEndEditing.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{  
     double delayInSeconds = 2.0;    

     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds 
       * NSEC_PER_SEC);   

     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ 
          textField.isSecureTextEntry = YES;  

     });

}
```

Comment: @Swift_prasad Then why did you accept this answer ?

Comment: By making some change I got my expected output.. @Sneha

Comment: @Swift_prasad Then please add that as the answer so that it will help others who face the same issue.